# How to make a part of string bold?

Tags: javascript, html, string, formatting

I have this `html`>`select` lists which gives u a quick review of the item but there is this one specific
part of the string where i wanna make a word bold but not working anyways. I have come across a similar question being asked here, tried them, not working.
can you please help me on this?

here is the specific part of this switch statement -

```
 let str = "BEWARE!";

para.textContent = "a leather rebel,menace crafated glove,that charges up"+
        ", holds an insane amount of energy until it is unleashed anyway you want it to but"+
         str.bold() +" for it may burn you instead if not released in time!";
```

Comment: Please, post what's "para" and how your select is generated.

Comment: 'para' has been used as a constant here.Such as - 

const para = document.querySelector('p');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use innerHTML instead of textContent and it will go for what you need

check the snippet

```js
let str = 'BEWARE!';
let para = document.querySelector('p');
para.innerHTML = "a leather rebel,menace crafated glove,that charges up"+
        ", holds an insane amount of energy until it is unleashed anyway you want it to but " +
         str.bold() +  " for it may burn you instead if not released in time!";
```

```html
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `String.bold()` function only wrap your string into <b> tags.

The context of usage could not support HTML Tags.

Tip: It's a "bad" practice to use <b> tags only for visual bold effect. You better do it with CSS!